# How can I run only the build script from Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is there a way to run only the build.rs build script from Cargo?  I'd like to generate some headers with cbindgen without building anything else.

Comment: [but why ?](https://media.giphy.com/media/s239QJIh56sRW/giphy.gif)

Comment: You may try creating cargo workspace with multiple package,  one can be your project's package(default) other one can be the noop package which will be a placeholder to run your build.rs

Comment: i wonder is cargo-script or cargo-play could help you run that rust file without any special setup

Comment: I like the idea of creating a noop package placeholder, but not sure how to go about it - any examples that you're aware of?

Comment: @GrahamMacDonald this can be an example: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html